# XYAreaChart the colors of the shapes on the chart merge

Tags: java, jfreechart

Using `setSeriesPaint`, I set the colors for the series: red and black. You can see the problem in the picture:
[image] Instead of black, there is something in between black and red, because, apparently, there is an overlay on red. How to solve this problem?

```
        TimeSeries all = new TimeSeries( "All" );
        TimeSeries heal = new TimeSeries( "Heal" );
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(. . .).get();
        Elements h = document.select("tr");
        int a = 0;
        for(int i = h.size()-1;i>1;i--) {
            String[] mas = String.valueOf(h.get(i).text()).split(" ");
            SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd.MM.yyyy");
            Date da = ft.parse(mas[0]);
            Day d = new Day(da);
            all.add(d, Double.parseDouble(mas[10]));
            heal.add(d, Double.parseDouble(mas[4]));
        }
        TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(all);
        dataset.addSeries(heal);
        JFreeChart lineChartObject = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart(. . .);
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) lineChartObject.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.black);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.black);
        DateAxis domain = new DateAxis("Дата");
        plot.setDomainAxis(domain);

        XYAreaRenderer movingAverageRenderer = new XYAreaRenderer();
        movingAverageRenderer.setUseFillPaint(false);
        movingAverageRenderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red);
        movingAverageRenderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.black);
        plot.setRenderer(movingAverageRenderer);

        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;
        File lineChart = new File( "C://gr", "graph.jpeg");
        ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(lineChart ,lineChartObject, width ,height);
```

Comment: This looks like a limitation of JPEG, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20jpeg%20pink). Try `saveChartAsPNG`.